# Typescript "as const" unexpectedly takes intersection of arrays

Tags: typescript

```
const data = [
  {
    foo: [1, 2],
  },
  {
    foo: [2, 3],
  },
] as const;

const result = data.filter((i) => {
  return i.foo.includes(3); // error: Argument of type '3' is not assignable to parameter of type '2'.(2345)
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAsAKBjAb133wDMQQAuTARgBoYAmAXTuJgF829D2yLqGRgwDMrdl1zMYCCDFCQoAbly4F0GACcAphACuAG1jpEyAHSkAlke2aAFHcsBKNAD5ePHVD2awMSxYUZpZgwAZ6cLp2Ik5KMAD08TC2miCa1ACCmgDmegC22mCwIKQwUACeAA7aMADkIrX+cmAgsLIQltlgCABGBjVQIDCVCJoIBVC2MCVlVTW1jLVmdowiACwArE64HLG4QA)

Typescript doesn't let me write the code above, showing the said error. I don't know how typescript interpret "as const", but it's not as what I understand it.

How can I fix this code? `data` is a hardcoded dictionary (quite large in my real codebase). I don't want to do `return (i.foo as number[]).includes(3)` because I do want to guard against any other values that are not 1,2,3. That's the whole point of using `as const`.

Comment: If you know the values  of the array at compile time, why would you be using `includes`?

Comment: Definitely, in as the playground shows if you hover over `.foo` the value and definition of `i` is `readonly [1, 2] | `readonly [1, 3]`, the first one is not possible to `.includes(3)`. Removing `as const` will remove the error message since `.includes` is allowable on `number[]`

Comment: @NathanWiles In my project, `data` is a large hardcoded dictionary, I want to use part of it to do something, use other parts for some other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different options (depending on your use case I suppose):

1. Define the type of `data` upfront
   a. this is probably a more preferred approach as it's clear to later readers
2. Pick a different function to find the array with the value you're after
3. Not set `data` to be a `const`
4. Tell typescript that the object is an `any` type
   a. this method I do not recommend because you lose the benefit of TypeScript

##### Method 1

Defining the type of `data` may be the clearest approach for later readers.
I'm not sure if `as const` is then no longer necessary, or if they then help the compiler out. You don't have to make a change and can still use `.includes`

```js
type DataType = {
  foo: number[]
}[];

const data:DataType = [
  {
    foo: [1, 2],
  },
  {
    foo: [2, 3],
  },
] as const;

const result = data.filter((i) => {
  return i.foo.includes(3);
});
```

##### Method 2

You could pick an alternative, but you may end up with some performance hit, `find` and `findIndex` don't throw an error:

```js
const data = [
  {
    foo: [1, 2],
  },
  {
    foo: [2, 3],
  },
] as const;
```

```js
const result = data.filter((i) => {
  return !!i.foo.find((v => v=== 3))
});

const result = data.filter((i) => {
  return i.foo.findIndex((v => v=== 3)) !== -1
});
```

##### Method 3

Not setting `data` as a `const` is enough to allow TypeScript to be ok again. This is because the type of `i.foo` goes from `readonly [1, 2] | readonly [1, 3]` to simply `number[]`, and `.includes` is then an accepted function on that type

```js
const data = [
  {
    foo: [1, 2],
  },
  {
    foo: [2, 3],
  },
];

const result = data.filter((i) => {
  return i.foo.includes(3);
});
```

##### Method 4

Even the [TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#:%7E:text=any,every%20usage%20of%20the%20variable.) are clear that you shouldn't use `any` except for the mitigation cirumstances they mention.
If you go down this route, you are then free to "blindly" type code and you are risking the code breaking at runtime. It also comes with significant danger since you lose all the powerful type-checking that TypeScript provides.
It's heavily recommended that you **don't do this method**!

```js
const data = [
    {
        foo: [1, 2],
    },
    {
        foo: [2, 3],
    },
] as const;

const result = data.filter((i: any) => {
    return i.foo.includes(3);
});
```

Comment: Marked as accepted answer because method 2 is good. I also don't think there's an performance penalty as both `.find()` and `.includes()` should be O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is common problem, because includes is strictly generic.
There is library called `ts-reset` that solves few typescript problems including this. It is initialed once in app and you can choose to only use this particular fix by using `import '@total-typescript/ts-reset/array-includes'`

https://www.totaltypescript.com/ts-reset

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I found the `ts-reset` package to be very unusual, like nothing I've seen before - 1. it has a surprisingly high number of github stars 2. it has a very high install count on npm 3. the npm page and github README doesn't include how to use it 4. the official doc site looks very commercial 5. the "how to use" part in the official doc site doesn't show anything, which appears to be a bug, which means people can't easily find how to use it. Can you comment on these observations? Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do like this.

You need to add the type of object in parameter `(i)` to `(i: any)`, and it solves your problem.

```
const data = [
    {
        foo: [1, 2],
    },
    {
        foo: [2, 3],
    },
] as const;

const result = data.filter((i: any) => {
    return i.foo.includes(3);  // [{ "foo": [2,3] }] 
});

console.log(result);
```

I also mentioned a link for your confirmation, please check the below link and run that code.

[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeOexAZiCAFyYCMANDAEwC6tRuAvq8YcaeVRgb0AzCzYxOWJjAQQYoSFADcWLAugwATgFMIAVwA2sdImQA6EgEsj2zQAo7lqgjABPAJRoAfAXE6oeppgMJYW5GaWYMAGenC6dsLuSrgA9CmY+DAARGQgWQJCohLSWOxJquogBtpmBiAA5nY6+kZJQA](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeOexAZiCAFyYCMANDAEwC6tRuAvq8YcaeVRgb0AzCzYxOWJjAQQYoSFADcWLAugwATgFMIAVwA2sdImQA6EgEsj2zQAo7lqgjABPAJRoAfAXE6oeppgMJYW5GaWYMAGenC6dsLuSrgA9CmY%20DAARGQgWQJCohLSWOxJquogBtpmBiAA5nY6%20kZJQA)

Comment: using `any` defeats the purpose of Typescript, `any` should be considered a last resort

Comment: Yes, @Harrison this is the last resort, `any` Defeat many problems in Typescript, but sometimes it will give some warning.

Comment: It won't defeat the problem, only hide it. With this method I can now do `i.bar.includes(3)` and it will not warn me and crash when run because `i.bar` is `undefined` and you can't call `.includes` on `undefined`

Comment: Yes, But you don't have a key called `bar` in this array, that's why you get an error in `i.bar`, you need to add a key named `bar` in your array, and you cannot get an error.

Comment: I appreciate that point, but a later reader/developer might not know that something like `bar` doesn't exist; now TypeScript won't tell them and now the code is relying that someone is going to remember it about this potentially abstracted away object, which is dangerous for the code to rely on a person's memory

Comment: But, Maybe it's just an example code, `foo` and `bar` are commonly used as placeholder names for variables or objects. They are not specific keywords or predefined in any programming language;  they are chosen for their brevity and clarity in illustrating concepts.